# Add To Home Screen (Chrome) doesn't work with react routes

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I have a node.js/express server that serves a react website. When I use the "add to home screen" function in chrome (android), the only thing being save is the main url (example.com), not the route (example.com/my-route). When I click on the shortcut, the home page is being opened instead of the page saved.

Other browsers don't have this problem.

Any ideas what the reason might be? Technically the browser should simply save the currently opened URL.

p.s. I push every page to history, so technically there shouldn't be any issues.